# How to prevent direct access page through URL

Tags: php, redirect

please
How to write PHP code. prevent page direct URL access but access through button.
let suppose I have a button with link "www.demo.com/example.html".
someone click the button redirect this page "www.demo.com/example.html" but someone access through direct trough URL it show denied.
Someone help me collage project.

Answer (score 0):

Use form for secure unwanted access.

//SOURCE FILE

```
<form action="www.demo.com/example.html" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="SubmitButton">
</form>
```

//DESTINATION FILE

```
if(!isset($_POST["SubmitButton"])){
header("Location: SourceFile.php");}
```

In source file use submit button to redirect.

In destination file check "SubmitButton", If user try to access page using url then he/she will redirect to same page.

Answer (score 0):

method 1:

in js, you can use local storage

on the button page:

```
localStorage.setItem('fromButtonRedirect', 'yes');
```

on the redirected page:

```
const getData = localStorage.getItem('fromButtonRedirect');
if (getData === 'yes') {
// allowed...
}
else {
 // access is denied...
}

localStorage.removeItem('fromButtonRedirect');
```

method 2:

in php, you can add a query string

(but you file should be a php file [www.demo.com/example.php])

on button

again in example.php you can check using isset

if not set then, access is denied.

method 3:

you can add some identifier in .htaccess

or as posted from previous answer.